# <img src="data:... with gzipped file

Tags: javascript, html, image, base64, gzip

It's probably more like a theoretical question but still.

It is pretty simple to use inline `base64` data to pass it in image source parameter. We are doing it like that: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,[base64 string]" />`.

But what if the data that represented in this `base64` string is gzipped? Is there a way to tell the browser about it? It can be simply done when the image is loaded from a HTTP server by adding `Content-Encoding: gzip` header. But is it possible with the inline method?

I couldn't find any information about this. The only solution that I see is use JavaScript to "unbase64" the data, "gunzip" it and then "base64" it again and put it to the `src` attribute.

But it not seem to be a good solution...

Comment: If it's a zipped file from the server, it's no longer a base64 string is it ?

Comment: It is not a file. base64 is just a way to represent a binary data. So we can put any data in base64 string. We can encode for example a png file and and put this string in the `src` attribute saying that this is `image/png;base64`. But what is this image/png was firstly gzipped?

Comment: That it wouldn't be `image/png` so you'd be lying.

Comment: Exactly. But I couldn't find a mime-type for gzipped png. Actually there are no mime-types for gzipped files, you can only say to the browser that the transferring data is a gzipped data with the `Content-Encoding` header. But we don't have headers when we are using inline base64 data.

Answer (score 4):

Browsers support gzip encodings at the *transport* level (i.e. in HTTP). They don't have any support for it at the data level.

If you were to provide a base64 sting of gzipped data, then it wouldn't be `image/png` it would be `application/x-gzip` and the browser wouldn't be able to handle it because it would try to decode it as an image.

If you were to do that but use the correct MIME type, then the browser still wouldn't know what to do with it because it wouldn't be an image format and there is no support for decoding gzip data and then guessing at what format the data inside is.

> But we don't have headers when we are using inline base64 data.

The data has to come from somewhere. It is usually either embedded in an HTML document (in which case the entire document can be compressed when it is sent over HTTP) or generated locally from JavaScript (in which case there is no point in compressing it just to immediately decompress it, there's no network to send it over, so no performance gains to be had by compression).

Comment: Just imagine a situation where you can't use any external files or make request to any HTTP server and the size of the html+js is extremely limited to exact amount of bytes (don't ask me where this situation can appear :)). In this situation you want compress everything to the maximum. PNG encoded in base64 is 30-50% larger than the original PNG file, but if you gzip this file first you can win some bytes out of it... Unless the code that will be handling unzipping will be larger than saved bytes...

Comment: Then, to embed the gzipped data in the HTML document you'd have to represent it as text, which generally means base64, which will inflate the size right up again.

Answer (score -3):

"f you were to provide a base64 sting of gzipped data, then it wouldn't be image/png it would be application/x-gzip"

So?

Upon detection of the file has completed being unzipped, and in javascript, fixup the headers so it understands the data and eventually you'll end up with img src=data:blah blah

I don't know why we still worry about 7 bit and EBCDIC links. This is nonsense, image:data/png;gzip,... should work this isn't rocket science.

It removes the word "gzip" and replaces is with the string that's gzipped.

Someone bug the vivaldi people, they always put stuff in first.